# 301 redirect a query string

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

i'm trying to to do a 301 redirect for a query string but can't figure it out. This is what it would be if it were a regular 301:

Redirect 301 /vetements/robes-de-grossesse.html?limit=all http://www.domain.fr/vetements/robes-de-grossesse.html

Can anyone advise on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^limit=
RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

It will maintain the directory path but the '?' on the end will remove the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect (mod_alias) operates on URL paths only, which does not include the query string. You'll want to use mod_rewrite instead. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} limit=all
RewriteRule vetements/robes-de-grossesse.html http://www.domain.fr/vetements/robes-de-grossesse.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for the response but unfortunately this hasn't worked

Comment: I've given you all the tools you need to figure out the exact rule for your situation.